# Does anyone know how do the link between Rviz of ROS and the physical robot model?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, rviz, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,

I would like to do the link between rviz and my phisical robot, when my robotic arm move, i would like the same think into rviz ?

thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188755/does-anyone-know-how-do-the-link-between-rviz-of-ros-and-the-physical-robot-model-?/) by [a_le_ban](https://answers.ros.org/users/19920/a_le_ban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- This is usually done by creating a **URDF** (robot kinematic model) which defines the kinematics and joints of your robot, and loading it into the `robot_description` parameter.
- Your hardware driver then publishes the `joint_states` topic with the name and position of each joint mentioned in the URDF.
- The [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) node reads this `joint_states` topic and the URDF, and publishes the transform tree (TF) in full 3D for your robot.
- You can then visualize this in Rviz with the **Robot Model** display.

The [Using URDF with robot_state_publisher Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher) gives a more in-depth walkthrough of all of the steps in this process.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [a_le_ban](https://answers.ros.org/users/19920/a_le_ban/) on 2014-08-04**:
thank you for your help!